# Service onStop does not stop the service

Tags: android, android-service, android-broadcastreceiver

I have an service that pings every 10 seconds every activity subscribed to it.
This is my Service definition:

```
public class MyService extends Service {

private final static String TAG = "AccountSummaryService";
public static final String BROADCAST_ACTION = "com.mypackage.mobile";
private Handler handler = new Handler();
private final int delayedStartupTime = 1000;
private Intent intent;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    intent = new Intent(BROADCAST_ACTION);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags,  int startId) {
    handler.postDelayed(broadcast, 1000);
    return START_STICKY;
}

private Runnable broadcast = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        sendBroadcast(intent);
        handler.postDelayed(this, 10000);
    }
};

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    this.stopSelf();
    handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(broadcast);
}
```

In my activity I register/start and unregister/stop the servince in my onResume/onPause methods.
They are called so the following code actually gets executed:

```
//in the onCreate
Intent anIntent = new Intent(activity, MyService.class);

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    startSummaryRefreshService();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    stopSummaryRefreshService();
}

private void startSummaryRefreshService() {
    activity.startService(anIntent);
    activity.registerReceiver(myReceiverObject, new IntentFilter(RefreshUIService.BROADCAST_ACTION));
}

public void stopSummaryRefreshService() {
    activity.unregisterReceiver(myReceiverObject);
    activity.stopService(anIntent);
}
```

The problem is that even if the stopService() gets called the service still runs and when I re-register my receiver it gets called multiple times.

Basically... I can't stop the service in anyway. I've been trying many of the StackOverflow solutions but... no way.

What do I get wrong?

Comment: What do you mean when you "re-register my receiver" ? how do you do that? Are you showing the same activity again ? Also why are you calling the start/stop methods with "activity" ? What is that activity reference? are you calling this from outside the activity code?

Comment: Good question. It'm actually not re-starting the activity but a fragment.

Comment: Care to elaborate? or post more code?

Comment: Basically I have a main activity which switches between three fragments, one at a time, using a side menu. Only one of this fragment uses the service which has to start when it is chosen and it has to stop when the user choses another fragment.

Comment: The "activity" variable is just getActivity() called from the fragment.

Comment: When I wrote "The following code is my activity" I lied, that code is within my fragment. I lied because I didn't realise it could have been relevant.

Comment: So basically the service lifecycle is tied to however you handle the fragments when selected. How are you switching fragments?

Comment: Calling replace and passing a new instance of the fragment. Something like .replace(R.id.container, new MyFragment)

Comment: You need to make sure that the calls to the service start/stop are made in the right order. Debug your app and check how the fragments resume/pause executes your services.

Comment: Thanks for your support Robert first of all. I did debugged it: my receiver gets correctly registered and unregistered and perfectly started, it just doesn't stop. So when I move out from the fragment and I check logcat out I see that my service is not called as expected but the broadcast is still fired. Afterwards, when I navigate back to my fragment it starts a SECOND service witch gets called with the other. ...If I repeat that I will have three services and so on

Comment: `Service` is a singleton. Android will not create a new instance of a `Service` if there is already one running. You don't have 3 `Service` instances running. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answers guys. The problem was the timer. `onDestroy()` was correctly called but the the way I defined the cycle created an infinite loop because the runnable is an object itself, separated from the service (which is actually killed with the `onDestroy()`, and gets recreated every 10 seconds once started.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    this.stopSelf();
    handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(broadcast);
}
```

First of all, you do not need to call `this.stopSelf()` from within `onDestroy()` because `onDestroy()` is called when the `Service` has already been stopped.

Secondly, the call to `removeCallbacksAndMessages(broadcast)` doesn't remove the `Runnable` you posted to the `Handler`. This is why, even after you've stopped the `Service`, you still get the broadcast `Intent` every 10 seconds. The argument to `removeCallbacksAndMessages()` is not the `Runnable`, but the "token" (which you are not using).

To fix your problem, just call `removeCallbacks(broadcast)` instead. This method takes the `Runnable` as an argument, and will remove the posted `Runnable` from the `Handler` (which is what you want to do).

Answer (score -1):

Is your all binding closed?

A service can be used in two ways. You can bind to a service that was started with startService(). Like, a background service can be started by calling startService() with an Intent object that identifies the download to execute. Only later, possibly when the user wants to exercise some control over that download or get information about the download, would an activity establish a connection to the service by calling bindService(). In cases like this, stopService() will not actually stop the service until the last binding is closed.

A service will shut down after all bindService() calls have had their corresponding unbindService() calls. If there are no bound clients, then the service will also need stopService() if and only if somebody called startService() on the service.

So, there are a few possibilities here:

1)You still have bound clients (e.g., other activities), in which case you cannot stop the service until they unbind

2)Since both unbindService() and stopService() are asynchronous, something might be going haywire with the timing, in which case you may get better luck if you call stopService() from your ServiceConnection's onServiceDisconnected() method.

Also, bear in mind that the exact timing of the service being destroyed is up to android os and may not be immediate. So, for example, if you are relying upon onDestroy() to cause your service to stop some work that is being done, consider using another trigger for that (e.g., activity calling a stopDoingStuff() method through the service binder interface).

Comment: onBind returns null so no binding.

Comment: why downvote? I have explained the concept of service binding.

Comment: So did the documentation. Your answer is unrelated to the issue. OP's service returns `null` in `onBind` method which means the service cannot be bound. If you're going to say "it might help someone else", this is not the first time bound services are discussed. Please keep the site clean. Thank you.